# How do I check if matches on a left join ALL have a match on another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, left-join

I am attempting to write a stored procedure that will return only records who either didn't yield any results on the right side of a `LEFT JOIN` **or** for **all** of the records found on the right side, only return a result set for those who have a match in another table.

To illustrate what I'm attempting to achieve, first consider the following table definitions:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TvpDocumentsSent] AS TABLE
(
      DocumentId INT
    , RecipientId INT
    , TransactionId INT
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Recipients]
(
      RecipientId INT
    , GroupId INT
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo[.[RecipientEmails]
(
      RecipientId INT
    , TransactionID INT
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DocumentTransactions]
(
      TransactionId INT
    , DocumentId INT
)
```

The first table, `TvpDocumentsSent` is used in the stored procedure as a table-valued parameter. It is indicative of the records that we are checking.

The second table, `Recipients` houses all of the potential document recipients. It is worth noting that recipients are placed in groups (indicated by the `GroupId`). All recipients in a group should receive a document **before** that document is marked as *ready-for-archive*. That is the part that I'm struggling with, btw.

Next, the `RecipientEmails` table houses all e-mails (that may or may not have contained a document) that have been sent to a recipient.

The latter table, `DocumentTransactions` stores a log of all document transactions that have occurred. This tells me what document was sent (indicated by the `DocumentId`). Although there is **not** a `RecipientId` on this table, the `TransactionId` can be used to trace the DocumentTransaction back to a recipient via the `RecipientEmails` table.

What I'm struggling with is how to write a query that gives me only a subset of the records passed in via `TvpDcoumentsSent`; only those who either don't have another recipient waiting for the document in the group **or** all recipients have received the document (i.e. there is a record in the `DocumentTransactions` table whose `TransactionId` maps back to a record in `RecipientEmail` whose recipient was eligible for this document).

What I've come up with so far is this (Note: I'm aware that I'm using `TvpDocumentsSent` as a table and not a TVP in the query below. I did this to simplify my explanation.

```
SELECT 
    SNT.DocumentId
FROM [dbo].[TvpDocumentsSent] AS SNT
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Recipients] AS RCP ON -- The recipient who recieved the document during this transaction.
        RCP.RecipientId = SNT.RecipientId
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Recipients] AS OTHR_RCP ON -- Other recipients who may have already received the document or could later.
        RCP.GroupId = OTHR_RCP.GroupId 
        AND RCP.RecipientId != OTHR_RCP.RecipientId
WHERE OTHR_RCP.RecipientId IS NULL OR ??????
```

Keeping in mind that there are n number of recipients who could potentially receive the document, how do I fulfill the `OR` portion of the `WHERE` clause to ensure that everyone has received documents?

I tried the following and it does not work correctly:

```
SELECT 
    SNT.DocumentId
FROM [dbo].[TvpDocumentsSent] AS SNT
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Recipients] AS RCP ON -- The recipient who recieved the document during this transaction.
        RCP.RecipientId = SNT.RecipientId
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Recipients] AS OTHR_RCP ON -- Other recipients who may have already received the document or could later.
        RCP.GroupId = OTHR_RCP.GroupId 
        AND RCP.RecipientId != OTHR_RCP.RecipientId
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[DocumentTransactions] AS DT ON
        SNT.TransactionId = DT.TransactionId
WHERE OTHR_RCP.RecipientId IS NULL OR DT.DocumentId IS NOT NULL
```

That won't work because as long as one of the recipients have received the document, the `OR` part of the `WHERE` clause will pass. Let's say 5 recipients should received the document but only 1 has received it thus far. That `OR` will see the 1 record's match and pass the `WHERE`; that's wrong...It should enforce that **ALL** potential recipients have received the document.

Comment: If you need that all match or none, then you need to group by and count the total vs the total that match. Result must be filtered where the total that match is 0 or equal than the total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if the example below is getting close.
Since I had to mock up the sample data & guess the expected results.

But aggregating in a sub-query and then comparing totals could probably help here.
(or via a HAVING clause)

**Example snippet:**

```
declare @Recipients table (RecipientId int primary key, GroupId int);
declare @DocumentTransactions table (TransactionId int primary key, DocumentId int);
declare @DocumentsSent table (DocumentId int, RecipientId int, TransactionId int);
declare @RecipientEmails table (RecipientId int, TransactionID int);

insert into @Recipients (RecipientId, GroupId) values 
 (201,1),(202,1),(203,1),(204,2),(205,2),(206,2);
insert into @DocumentTransactions (TransactionId, DocumentId) values 
 (301,101),(302,101),(303,101),(304,102),(305,102),(306,102);
insert into @DocumentsSent (DocumentId, RecipientId, TransactionId) values 
 (101,201,301),(101,202,302),(101,203,303)
,(102,204,304),(102,205,305),(102,206,306);
insert into @RecipientEmails (RecipientId, TransactionId) values 
 (201,301),(202,302),(203,303)
,(204,304);

SELECT DocumentId 
FROM
(
    SELECT 
     tr.DocumentId, 
     rcpt.GroupId, 
     count(distinct sent.RecipientId) AS TotalSent,
     count(distinct rcptmail.RecipientId) AS TotalRcptEmail
    FROM @DocumentsSent AS sent
    LEFT JOIN @Recipients AS rcpt ON rcpt.RecipientId = sent.RecipientId
    LEFT JOIN @DocumentTransactions AS tr
           ON (tr.TransactionId = sent.TransactionId AND tr.DocumentId = sent.DocumentId)
    LEFT JOIN @RecipientEmails AS rcptmail
           ON (rcptmail.TransactionId = sent.TransactionId AND rcptmail.RecipientId = sent.RecipientId)
    GROUP BY tr.DocumentId, rcpt.GroupId
) AS q
WHERE (TotalSent = TotalRcptEmail OR (TotalSent > 0 AND TotalRcptEmail = 0))
GROUP BY DocumentId;

/*
SELECT
 tr.TransactionId, 
 sent.DocumentId, 
 sent.RecipientId AS RecipientIdSent, 
 rcpt.GroupId AS GroupIdRcpt, 
 rcpt.RecipientId AS RecipientIdRcpt, 
 rcptmail.RecipientId AS RecipientIdEmail
FROM @DocumentsSent AS sent
LEFT JOIN @Recipients AS rcpt ON rcpt.RecipientId = sent.RecipientId
LEFT JOIN @DocumentTransactions AS tr
           ON (tr.TransactionId = sent.TransactionId AND tr.DocumentId = sent.DocumentId)
LEFT JOIN @RecipientEmails AS rcptmail
           ON (rcptmail.TransactionId = sent.TransactionId AND rcptmail.RecipientId = sent.RecipientId);
*/
```

**Returns:**

```
DocumentId
----------
       101
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. I'm in the process now of trying this out. I will let you know if it works.

Comment: This worked! With some minor changes (this was a watered down representation of the real thing) it worked well. The main thing that helped was the sub query and the proper use of GROUP BY the aggregate the counts properly; that’s the thing that I struggled with. Thanks!

Comment: @BrandonAvant Hey, that's cool. I was worried that I had misunderstood your intentions. Since I found that requirement of "all or none" a bit peculiar.  But if it brought you closer to your solution, then all is well.

Comment: Yeah, it did require some tweaking to completely match the full requirements. Again, I modified/watered down what I posted here for complexity’s sake. The push in the right direction is what the doctor ordered.